# Pop-up dialog or Activity from Service running in Background in Android when keyguard is locked?

Tags: android, user-interface, service

I have an application in which there will be a service continuously running in background and on certain conditions service should call an activity or pop-up a dialog. I think this is possible.

The question is, in case device keyguard gets on say after 2 minutes of idle time then will the service continue running in background. And what will happen when the condition of opening pop-up or Activity is reached.

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your popup will popup below the keyguard. That is the point of the keyguard. So the user doesn't accidently hit your important dialog without actually reading it first.

Once the user unlocks the phone, your popup will be displayed.

Comment: Yes, but the op was asking how to get past it, if possible. There are uses cases outside pockets.